# qtranslate plugin and ajax requests

Tags: ajax, qtranslate

I'm trying to obtain the correct content for each language (I'm using qtranslate plugin in Wordpress environment) loaded by Ajax calls.

Every time, contents are shown up only in the default language.

I'm thinking about to pass the default-language-qtranslate variable into the ajax calls but I don't know how.

Maybe someone out here has already solved this issue..?

Thanks guys

Comment: Hi, i found this solution: http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2047&p=8586&hilit=ajax#p8586, but I don't know how to adopte these codes..do you know it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will help you to fix the default language request in Mailpress, or any other plugin.

Search in code for link request "ajax.php". Replace "ajax.php" with `ajax.php/?lang='.qtrans_getLanguage()`

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for my late, I've found the same solution by myself and now it works grate!

Comment: What effect does the `/` (slash) have before the `?` (question mark)? I don't recognize that syntax – is it a typo?

Comment: if i select the option ,Use Pre-Path Mode (Default, puts /en/ in front of URL). SEO friendly, from back end then the ajax doesn't work