# Ajax + qtranslate

Tags: ajax, wordpress, qtranslate

Hi I ran into the same problem as [Rik had here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571643/qtranslate-plugin-and-ajax-requests?rq=1)

The answer given was that he had to "Search in code for link request "ajax.php". Replace "ajax.php" with ajax.php/?lang='.qtrans_getLanguage()" "

My question is this (I know it might sound stupid, I suck at this stuff), what code does this answer refer to and where do I find it? I've searched all php files in the qtranslate and ajax plugins but cannot find where it is.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on which WP ajax-plugin you have a problem with. In case "Category-Post AJAX Tree" I had to replace

```
$localize = array ('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
```

with

```
$localize = array ('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php?lang='.qtrans_getLanguage()),
```

in cat-post-tree-ajax.php and to replace

```
var url = CatPostAjax.ajaxurl + '?action=myajax-submit&category=' + id; // compose url
```

with

```
var url = CatPostAjax.ajaxurl + '&action=myajax-submit&category=' + id; // compose url
```

in cat-post-tree-ajax.js. Please tell us what plugin you mean so we'll be able to help.