# qTranslate do not detect properly when called from inside a plugin through ajax

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp, qtranslate, mo

I got two problems.

**Problem 1:**

1. I have translated mailchimp's pot file into two languages. The .mo has been tested to be working.
2. But WP fails to show the ajax returns for other languages for the mailchimp form and/or widget for [mailchimp list subscribe form](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mailchimp/).

I got around this by modifying the `mailchimp.php` like following:

```
    $textdomain = 'mailchimp_i18n'; #line 57 to start
    if (defined('WPLANG'))
        $lang=WPLANG;
    $locale = apply_filters( 'plugin_locale', $lang, $textdomain);
```

***How did I figure out?***
In place of this `$lang` variable, default `mailchimp.php` has `get_locale()` defined in `l10n.php` of `wp-includes`.

When I placed a `print_r($locale)` before modifying as above. It shows the correct language set at wp-config's WPLANG. But when the mailchimp form is submitted it gets just default en_US!

***Where does it get the en_US, when I haven't set it?***
I found it very weird, `line 48-49` of `l10n.php` for definition of `get_locale()` contains:

```
    if ( empty( $locale ) )
    $locale = 'en_US';
```

Which, I think gets $locale as empty while in my case was called from the form. Which is very unlikely! But it happens in four instances of my testing.

***What my modification at mailchimp.php gets me to?***
I can now get the other language (ie Arabic) strings to my mailchimp form responses. But as its detected from WPLANG, I cannot switch to English in site's English mode.

**Problem 2:**
To switch languages on the fly. I used `qtrans_getLanguage()` in place of `get_locale()` in the mailchimp.php's code part. Thus, it becomes:

```
$locale = apply_filters( 'plugin_locale', qtrans_getLanguage(), $textdomain);
```

If I print_r($locale) after this line. It shows current language. But not when the form is submitted. The form's response always shows it as (en)!.

Now, **problem1** is very unlikely to happen and is unusual. But for **problem2** I definitely think there is a smart work around. Why would the qTranslate report wrong while called from the Ajax of that form?

Also, I do not want to modify core plugin files. Currently, I had to modify mailchimp.js to manually match and replace common strings(And I hate it!).

Comment: Found some hint [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800630/ajax-qtranslate) but not yet sure if I just need to

         `'ajax_url' => trailingslashit(home_url().'/'.  qtrans_getLanguage()),` at line 96 of `mailchimp.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800630/ajax-qtranslate?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571643/qtranslate-plugin-and-ajax-requests?rq=1)

But as mailchip.js has this 'ajax_url' I searched in the mailchimp plugin where this URL is generated from. Its generated at line number 96 in mailchimp.php

```
    'ajax_url' => trailingslashit(home_url().'/'.  qtrans_getLanguage()),
```

I just added the `'/'.  qtrans_getLanguage()` part.

Comment: With the above change I just removed the other changes I made to `mailchimp.php`